# Monitor number of records returned in a long-running SELECT statement during SSAS processing

Tags: sql-server, ssas, dmv

On a SQL Server 2014, I have an SSAS tabular model which is querying a relational clustered columnstore table (with 800 mio. records), when the model is being processed. The query is just a simple SELECT statement with no joins, filters, etc. I am processing the model through an XMLA command, which is being fired by a SQL Server Agent job. The processing takes a couple of hours.

To get an idea of the progress of the processing, I would like to know the number of records returned so far by the SELECT statement. Is there any way to do this, when I know the SPID of the SELECT statement?

`sys.dm_exec_requests` does not seem to contain any record count information.

Also, I have tried to look in the DMV's of Analysis Services, to see if any of these objects could give me the information I need, but no luck.

The reason I think it must be possible to obtain this information somehow, is that when I process the tabular model through the graphical IDE of SSMS, it actually shows the row count while processing.

**Update:** It turns out the `sys.dm_exec_requests` DMV actually has a `row_count` column. Unfortunately, the contents of this column does not seem to reflect reality. For the first hour or so of processing, it had the value of "3", but I know from experience that several million records would have been returned within the first hour.

Comment: Have you tried `sys.dm_exec_query_profiles`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn223301.aspx

Comment: Just did. This dmv does not return any records. Looks like I had to enable `SET STATISTICS PROFILE ON` before I started the processing, for this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you connect SQL Server Profiler to SSAS and watch the [Progress Report Current](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175334.aspx) events with an EventSubclass=ReadData the [IntegerData column will show the cumulative rows read so far for that SSAS partition.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175667%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)

> Integerdata:   Contains the integer data associated with the reported
>   event, such as the current count of the number of rows processed for a
>   processing event.